# Terminating maven-jetty-plugin running in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty, m2eclipse

I'm using maven-jetty-plugin to quickly run and debug WebApp I'm developing under Eclipse/m2eclipse.
It starts ok and I can fully use the debugger, but I cannot stop the application gracefully.

When I do ctrl+c in the console view it just does nothing although in the launcher configuration "allocate console" is enabled.

In simple java projects the ctrl+c option works fine (tested on windows). So it seems like some remote/embedded jvm problem. My application uses persistent JMS queues, so after every restart I need to manually kill the session on the other server. This isn't very agile.

Anyone has an idea what's the source of the issue? Or maybe there is some known workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your using the m2eclipse plugin you can run maven directly from eclipse.

1 Go to you debug configurations and under maven build create a new entry.
2 Give it a name.
3 Select the base directory of your maven project.
4 for a goal enter jetty:run then click the debug button.

All should be good.  you can kill it from the console view inside of eclipse.  All breakpoints should work as usual.

To gracefully shutdown the application from eclipse you have to do the following.
Add the following configuration to your pom for the jetty plugin.  The important part here is the stop key and the stop port.

```
<configuration>
    <tmpDir>target/not/necessary</tmpDir>
    <webAppConfig>
        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
    </webAppConfig>
    <stopPort>9966</stopPort> 
    <stopKey>jetty-stop</stopKey>
</configuration>
```

Next add another run configuration for maven but this time set the goal to jetty:stop.  It will  perform a graceful shutdown.

In order to make it more automatic: the goal can be set to jetty:stop jetty:start. In this way if the process is not running there will be a small warning but booting process will continue. Otherwise the 
other process will be gracefully shut down and then serwer will be started.

Only one command is needed and it can be run by one shortcut (run last build) reducing context switching.

Comment: That is what I was doing from the start. Maybe I'm not clear. I can kill the process using "red button", but it will not perform proper shutdown.
When I stop the process after starting it from command line using ctrl+c it will perform correct cleanup.
But ctrl+c doesn't work in the scenario you have described (at least on my machine - virtualboxed windows xp).

Comment: Ok.  Sorry I missed that part of your question.  I have added to my answer on how to gracefully shutdown jetty from eclipse.

Comment: This is a way that should work. I'll accept that answer. Its not as comfortable I would like to, but it should do the job.
Thank you.

Comment: I had a small epiphany today. If I add jetty:stop goal before jetty:start it works great. I'll update your answer.

Comment: Is that configuration supposed to go in the webapp's main pom.xml, or are you saying there is one somewhere for the jetty plugin itself specifically?

Comment: OK, looks like that should be inserted within the jetty <plugin> tag, within main pom.xml...  But when I do that and run the jetty:stop run config, I get this:  Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903:stop (default-cli) on project PrioriGram: The parameters 'stopPort', 'stopKey' for goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903:stop are missing or invalid

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround 1**

1. From a command prompt, cd to your webApp project (where a main pom.xml is for example).
2. Run Jetty from there with `mvn jetty:run`
3. Killing with ctrl+c works from there! (at least with Windows cmd)

**Workaround 2**

1. Install [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/)
2. [Install the *Kill Application* plugin](https://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) on your new VisualVM
3. Right-click on the Jetty Application in VisualVM's list, and 'Kill Application'